# Get ChekBox Component in Gridview Inside Content Template

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have this aspx snippet:

```
<asp:updatepanel runat="server" id="resultPanel">
    <contenttemplate>
            <app:exgridview id="referenceGridView" runat="server" allowpaging="True" allowsorting="True">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="checkAllBox" runat="server" CausesValidation="false"></asp:CheckBox> 
                </HeaderTemplate>
<asp:TemplateField>
.....
```

How do I get `checkAllBox` component in `.vb` code behind?

I have tried this:

`referenceGridView.HeaderRow _
                        .Cells(0).FindControl("checkAllBox")`

And

`referenceGridView.FindControl("checkAllBox")`

but it doesn't work neither.

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:GridView OnRowDataBound="MyGridView_RowDataBound" ... />
Then define MyGridView_RowDataBound:

 void CustomersGridView_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
 {
   Label l = (Label) e.Row.FindControl("lblName");
 }
```

Comment: In your case cast as checkbox

Comment: Could we get the control without Row Event?

Comment: If you look at the generated html you will see that it only makes sense in the row event because that's the only place that the control can be found as the control id is non unique otherwise

Answer (score 0):

### EDITED

You can find the control in GridView.HeaderRow:

**NOTE :** This code block should be executed after `referenceGridView.DataBind()`. I am running this in a button click:

```
Protected Sub btnTest_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnTest.Click

Dim checkAllBox As CheckBox = TryCast(referenceGridView.HeaderRow.FindControl("checkAllBox"), CheckBox)

If checkAllBox IsNot Nothing Then
    'checkAllBox exists here.
    'Place your code for checkAllBox 
    If checkAllBox.Checked Then
        lblResult.Text = "All checked"
    Else
        lblResult.Text = "All not checked"
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Presuming that you already have this in page load:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    'clear xml on page load if it contain data
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        'Getting datasource
        'referenceGridView.DataSource = MyDataSource.GetTable()
        referenceGridView.DataBind()
    End If

End Sub
```

And my test button in markup:

```
<asp:button  id="btnTest" runat="server"  Text="TEST" />
```

And you can download the test project [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6i8p65gmkp0LWw1Z2FvU3lUQkE/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: I don't know why `referenceGridView.Rows` always returning `Nothing`